# cannot insert the value null into column ... when the value is not null

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

in my c# code I have an insert into my DB, but it throws an exception

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BoxID', table 'Moroccanoil_Replicated.dbo.Boxes'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

however when debugging this piece of code I see that the box is actually not null, therther more when i test the same exact insert in my SQL SM It works just fine.

**Edit:**

For some reason this is the query that is actually being executed according to the profiler :

```
exec sp_executesql 
  N'INSERT [dbo].[Boxes]([MasterBoxID], [DateTime], [Reported], [StationID])
  VALUES (NULL, @0, @1, @2)
  SELECT [BoxID]
  FROM [dbo].[Boxes]
  WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [BoxID] = scope_identity()',
  N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 bit,@2 int',@0='2015-11-30 13:37:46.4714394',@1=0,@2=7
```

Does anyone know why is this and how to fix it?

More relevant information :

- The exception occurs on the db.SaveChanges() call and not on the insert.
- The BoxID is not defined as identity.

Here is the code in debug mode with the inserted values:
[image]

And the same insert in SQL that works just fine:
[image]

Comment: Exception message is quite self explanatory. Can you please show your work as well?

Comment: Show some code related to this.

Comment: Are you using the same context on multiple threads and/or concurrent async contexts? This might very well be a concurrency issue.

Comment: You are trying to insert NULL into a column that does not allow NULL, that's for sure. You must be looking at a wrong place when you think that the value is not NULL. It is not possible to tell more with the information you provided.

Comment: What I'd do, is fire up the SQL profile, and watch the SQL query in question run, then cross check it against your C# code.

Comment: Thank you for the pictures. Apparently this particular entity/instance does not have this problem. It must be a different one that does.

Comment: I added the code of the insert with a snap of the values, I know what the exception means I can't figure out my is it being thrown when the values are not null.

Comment: @zespri that is the only place in my code that preforms inserts into this table.

Comment: Is `BoxID` not the primary key column? Would it not be set to `NULL` by Entity Framework, to be replaced by a generated ID chosen by the database? How did you define the `BoxID` property?

Comment: Profiler to see the *actual* sql being executed, the SQL you *think* is being executed is irrelevant.

Comment: They are null, believe me. You just have not discovered how this happened yet. =) Look at the sql trace in the profiler. It's likely you'll find that more then one entity is being inserted.

Comment: Another possible cause that your mapping somehow is incorrect. And another debugging technique is to try and create a minimal reproducible example. I bet, you'll find the cause before you finish.

Comment: Should you not be using 'Attach' rather than 'Add' ?  If the box already has an Id that must mean it already exists in the context ... (which is what Jean is alluding to)

Comment: @HughJones no, the box is totaly new.

Comment: which means it should not yet have an Id?

Comment: No, the BoxID is not the identity of the table, it is an arbitrery value of my own

Comment: Ok, I finally installed profiler without uninstalling by sql-server-manegment since I did not had one installed, the output of the profiler is aaded to the post.

Comment: Most likely EF won't pass the ID parameter because it thinks the value is created by the database. This means you should turn off DatabaseGeneratedOptions.Identity for this column.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro That was it! please migrate your comment to an answer so I could accepte it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in comments:

Most likely EF won't pass the ID parameter because it thinks the value is created by the database. This means you should turn off DatabaseGeneratedOptions.Identity for this column.

With DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity, EF won't pass the ID value to the database because it suspects it to be given by DBMS. This can lead to this issue or an DbUpdateConcurrencyException, when it suspects an object with a given Id value to be in the database, but it was actually altered by DBMS.

Comment: removed StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" from Id column in EDMX and it worked. +1

Comment: This was also my case, I just set the Identity to None so I can manually put the value of the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned, EF does not pass ID column to the database. If you have a case that you don't want to have auto increment value, below is an example

```
public class PackingInventory
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
```