# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table '; column does not allow nulls

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

I'm seeing a strange behavior from Entity Framework. I'm using code-first approach to define a One-To-Many relationship between two entities:

```
public class IncomingCheck : AuditedEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual CheckType Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Bank Bank { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<IncomingCheckHistory> History { get; set; }
}

public class IncomingCheckHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And here's I I'm trying to add an item to the `History`:

```
using (var db = new CheckDataContext())
{
    foreach (var check in SelectedItems)
    {
        var dbCheck = await db.IncomingChecks.FindAsync(check.Id);

        var history = new IncomingCheckHistory()
        {
            LongDescription = "something",
        };

        dbCheck.History.Add(history);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync(); //throws the exception
    }
}
```

But it throws an exception saying that "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'". However I've always done it like this. The database is supposed to fill the `Id` column itself with a unique number.

What am I missing?

#### Update:

Using SSProfiler, I got the query that runs on the database. It's as follows:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[IncomingCheckHistories]([LongDescription], [IncomingCheck_Id])
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[IncomingCheckHistories]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int',@0=N'Something',@1=1
```

Note that `scope_identity()` should be getting the Id itself, correct?

Comment: check the table design if ID is identity seeded, if it is then you will need to exclude it from the insert.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu It is. I'm using EF, how am I supposed to exclude it? Also since I've always added entities like this, why doesn't this one work?!

Comment: You can add incoming check and a corresponding forgien key prop to the history class and set the key with out getting the check. This will save you a db call and may fix the issue.

Comment: @rahicks Tried that too, no luck :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot insert the value null into column ... when the value is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995393/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-when-the-value-is-not-null)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the Id be set as the Identity?
Like this:

```
public class IncomingCheckHistory
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Hope that this is the solution to your problem!

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't adding the `Key` attribute set it as Identity though? Also why did you set `LongDescription` as `Key`? It's not a key for me. In any case I tried your solution. Doesn't fix it :(

Comment: No, the `Key` attribute doesn't set it as identity. Does it still throw the same error?

Comment: Yep. Exactly the same error. Actually I'm pretty sure it does because adding the attribute didn't change the database (meaning it didn't throw an exception saying that the model has been changed).

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855100/why-is-ef-trying-to-insert-null-in-id-column ?

Comment: This is handled by [key]. Are there any other props? Seems like something is missing

Comment: @rahicks no. I created another migration and copy/pasted the code directly from my solution.

Comment: @Pl4gue why nullable?

Answer (score 0):

Well for some strange reason the exact code worked after completely deleting the database and migrations and starting from scratch. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work without migrations. Also I had tried deleting the database before but at the time I was trying a little different code.

In any case the posted code/query should work. Also I checked the database and the columns to see if anything is different and it wasn't. I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on why it wasn't working and it is now.

Comment: previously your database column was not set to autoincrement/identity. EF would not pass any id value because it suspects it to be given by DBMS, but your database schema wasn't matching EF's model.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Before changing the DB, I checked the column. It was set as Identity, it had identity seeded and it was set as `PK, int, not null`.